# How can i define 2 different element with same unique name attribute in different scope and refer  their name to attributes

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

```
<!--Metamodel (root element)-->
  <xsd:element name="Metamodel">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element ref="Package"/>
        <xsd:element ref="EnumerationLiteral"/>
        <xsd:element ref="Class"/>
        <xsd:element ref="Operation"/>
        <xsd:element ref="Parameter"/>
        <xsd:element ref="Property"/>
        <xsd:element ref="PrimitiveType"/>
        <xsd:element ref="Enumeration"/>
      </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <!--OBJECT-->
  <xsd:complexType name="Object"  abstract="true"/>
  <!--ELEMENT-->
  <xsd:complexType name="Element" abstract="true">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="Object">
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <!--NAMED ELEMENT-->
  <xsd:complexType name="NamedElement" abstract="true">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="Element">
        <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:ID" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="Description" type="lib:Description" use="optional"/>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <!--TYPE-->
  <xsd:complexType name="Type" abstract="true">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="NamedElement">
        <xsd:attribute name="Package" type="lib:Package" use="optional"/>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <!--TYPED ELEMENT-->
  <xsd:complexType name="TypedElement" abstract="true">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="NamedElement">
        <xsd:attribute name="Type" use="optional"/>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <!--PACKAGE-->
  <xsd:element name="Package">
    <!--PACKAGE TYPE-->
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="NamedElement">
          <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element ref="OwnedType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element ref="NestedPackage" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xsd:all>
          <xsd:attribute name="NestingPackage" type="lib:NestingPackage"/>
          <xsd:attribute name="Uri" type="lib:Uri" use="optional"/>
        </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <!--ENUMERATIONAL LITERAL-->
  <xsd:element name="EnumerationLiteral" type="EnumerationLiteralType"/>
  <!--ENUMERATION LITERAL TYPE-->
  <xsd:complexType name="EnumerationLiteralType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="NamedElement">
        <xsd:attribute name="Enumeration" type="lib:Enumeration" use="optional"/>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <!--CLASS-->
  <xsd:element name="Class" type="ClassType"/>
  <!--CLASS TYPE-->
  <xsd:complexType name="ClassType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="Type">
        <xsd:all>
          <xsd:element ref="OwnedOperation" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xsd:element ref="OwnedAttribute" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xsd:element ref="SuperClass" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:all>
        <xsd:attribute name="IsAbstract" type="lib:IsAbstract"/>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

I have `Name` attribute on `NamedElement` element and this type is `ID`. Thats ok but i can't do:

```
<Metamodel>
  <Package Name="Serhat">
  </Package>
  <Class Name="Serhat"></Class>
</Metamodel>
```

There is a error i cant do this but i need to do this.

I need only one `Package` with `Name="Serhat"` but `Class` may be have `Nmae="Serhat"` and

another class in another package may have `Name="Serhat"` but this code can't do this.
How can i do this any idea ?

Comment: Element IDs should be unique.

Answer (score 1):

`xsd:ID` implies a global uniqueness constraint. If you want a uniqueness constraint that's not global, try adding a `xsd:unique` ([MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256146.aspx)) identity constraint to the containing element(s), which might be the doc root element.

```
<xsd:element name="Metamodel">
   ....
   <xs:unique name="uniquePackageNames">
     <xs:selector xpath="Package"/>
     <xs:field xpath="@Name"/>
   </xs:unique>
   <xs:unique name="uniqueClassNames">
     <xs:selector xpath="Class"/>
     <xs:field xpath="@Name"/>
     <xs:field xpath="@Package"/>
   </xs:unique>
</xsd:element>
```

Edit: Added Class/@Package field so that class name uniqueness is only within a package.

Comment: they problem with this solution is that you actually _want_ duplicated `Class`es, but only if they are in different `Package`s.

Comment: i used key and keyref but now i have problem to refer their name cause ; i have 2 scope on Class Name and dont know how to refer 2 key on 1 keyref

Comment: @gioele Updated for your comment. I didn't see the package/class linkage, but I guessed the missing OwnedType element is like TypedElement and has a Package attribute.

Comment: @gezgin I updated the answer to show using two fields, in case that's what you're getting at regarding "2 scopes".

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with `ID`? You say

> I have Name attribute on NamedElement element and this type is ID

but in your code you have

```
<xsd:attribute name="Name" type="lib:Name" use="optional"/>
```

is `lib:Name` defined as `xsd:ID`?

The meaning if `xsd:ID` is that you cannot have another element or name with such ID in the same document. If you want a more sophisticated method to define which ID are possible and how they can mix, you must use `xsd:NCName` as the type for the `Name` attribute and additional [Schematron rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schematron).

Schematron is used to express rules that cannot be expressed in XML Schema, in your case to say that different `Package`s must have different `Name` attributes but that `Class`es in different `Package` can have the same name.